# When I use getValues/setValues between sheets I loose formulas; when I us getFormulas/setFormulas I loose data

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to coding but think I need to loop through so getFormulas is returned for non formula data and setFormulas is returned for formulas.  Something like the following code but this is just a guess; it's the loop statement in particular I need help with.

```
function test() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ImpNewClient = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ImpNewClient");
  ImpNewClient.activate();
  var URL = ImpNewClient.getRange('B106').getValue();
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);  
  var Quotes = SS.getSheetByName("Quotes");
  var lastRow = Quotes.getRange(1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var source = Quotes.getRange("f2:f"+lastRow);
  var Values = source.getValues();
  var Formulas = source.getFormulas();
  var quotes = ss.getSheetByName('Quotes');
  var dest = quotes.getRange("f2:f"+lastRow);
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow-1; i++) {
  if (Formulas[i][0] !== "") {
    dest.setValue(Values[i][0]);
  } else {
    dest.setFormula(Formulas[i][0]);
  }
}
}
```

I tried getValues/setValues which returned everything as values including the formulas; conversely with getFormulas/setFormulas only the formulas were returned with non formula values returning an empty cell.  I assume this is has something to do with moving data between different workbooks.

What I am expecting is equivalent to what you would get if you used right click copy paste special formulas on a sheet range - which would return values as values and formulas as formulas.

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

Although I'm not able to test it, and I hope I didn't make any typos, I believe this sample script will copy both values and formulas to the destination range.  `getFormulas()` returns an array of strings representing the formulas in each cell.  These strings can simply be copied to the values array and then the values array can be put back using `setValues()`.

It is customary to start variable names with a lowercase letter.  Upper case is usually used for Class or Global variables.

All of the sheet activation, spreadsheet activation serve no purpose that I can see.    You simply need the source spreadsheet `ss2` and the destination spreadsheet `ss1`.

Once you `let newClient = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("NewClient");` the variable `newClient` retains a reference to that instance of the sheet named "NewClient".  You don't need to activate it to use it or any of its properties or methods.

**Script**

```
function myTest() {
  try {
    let ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let newClient = ss1.getSheetByName("NewClient");
    let url = newClient.getRange('B106').getValue();
    let ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    // Get quotes from ss2
    let quotes = ss2.getSheetByName("Quotes");
    let lastRow = quotes.getRange(1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    let source = quotes.getRange("f2:f"+lastRow);
    let values = source.getValues();
    let formulas = source.getFormulas();
    // Get destination range in ss1
    quotes = ss1.getSheetByName('Quotes');
    let dest = quotes.getRange("f2:f"+lastRow);
    for( let i=0; i<lastRow-1; i++ ) {  // Started in row 2
      if( formulas[i][0] !== "" ) {
        values[i][0] = formulas[i][0];
      }
    }
    dest.setValues(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
  if(dest.setFormulas[Formulas[i]] = ""){
    dest.setValues(Values[i][0]);
    dest.setFormulas(Formulas[i][0]);
  }
}
```

This way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
  if (Formulas[i][0] != "") {
    dest.setFormula(Formulas[i][0]);
  } else {
    dest.setValue(Values[i][0]);
  }
}
```

**Update**

Based on your spreadsheets the a final code should look like this:

```
function test() {

  var dest_ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newClient_sheet = dest_sheet.getSheetByName('ImpNewClient');
  var url        = newClient_sheet.getRange('B106').getValue();

  var source_ss  = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var src_sheet  = source_ss.getSheetByName('Quotes');
  var lastRow    = src_sheet.getRange(1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var source     = src_sheet.getRange('f2:f' + lastRow);

  var values     = source.getValues();
  var formulas   = source.getFormulas();

  var dest_sheet = dest_ss.getSheetByName('Quotes');

  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
    var cell = dest_sheet.getRange('f'+ (i + 2));
    if (formulas[i][0] !== '') { 
      cell.setFormula(formulas[i][0])
    }
    else { 
      cell.setValue(values[i][0])
    }
  }

  dest_sheet.activate()
}
```

And it's really confusing when you're using variables like `ss` / `SS`, and `quotes` / `Quotes` simultaneously. I'd advice you to use names like `dest_ss` / `src_ss`, `dest_sheet` / `src_sheet`.

And first letter in upper case (`Values`, `Formulas`, etc) means a class name usually, it makes sense don't use it for variables (`values`, `formulas`, etc).

Comment: Thanks both, I edited my code above, however this results in the formula from the "lastRow" from column f in the source sheet being entered in all cells from row 2 to lastRow in the destination sheet, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It hard to tell without the real spreadsheet. I just tired to change the code in my answer. Try it again.

Comment: Hi Yuri, whatever order it still uses the lastRow value for every cell, other than that the script works perfectly!; I've created a couple of sheets and would be grateful if you could take a look: [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V0_z3csirevyHJRJPbeiVqlws1R6M0hf0xbIakm72k8/edit?usp=sharing) [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nlc0Q9I93XAWFKlw_tdG79W4XSpS91r5T3PeXdlUl6A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the spreadsheets. They helped to understand what's going on. I've added the update to my answer.